# Need to add newline after performing some action in same file in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I want to give new line after task performed at same file .

Input : `sample.txt`

```
Hi   
Hello  
I am 
back

i am After new line  
you unable to get me.

..Sample_end.....
```

I grep the word starts from Hi and end with space and I also want print the grep words in the same file precedent with newline.

Output: `sample.txt`

```
Hi   
Hello  
I am 
back

i am After new line  
you unable to get me


Hi  
Hello  
I am   
back
```

Comment: So, did you try anything?

Comment: i tried this
`awk` -v RS= '/\[Hi\]/' `sample.txt`|tr [" "] <<sample.txt

Comment: I didn't quite get what you wanted, and I expect it to be the same for other people. Could you clarify a bit? Is the output what you want? Or what you already got? Could you also add some formatting (code or quote) around the file contents? Edit: never mind the last part, someone just did it.

Comment: yes this the expected output.i have to grep some words and paste those words with newline in the same file. getting some words form the file and paste those words at the same file with newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
    $ awk 'BEGIN {print ""} /Hi/,/^$/' file >> file
    $ cat file
    Hi
    Hello
    I am
    back

    i am After new line
    you unable to get me.

    Hi
    Hello
    I am
    back
```

It first appends a newline to `file` (`BEGIN {print}`) then stuff between `Hi` and an empty record (`^$`). Apparently `grep` wouldn't append to source file just by using `grep ... file >> file`.

Comment: @Sundeep Lol, not quite what I expected. :D I'm computer alliterate. Let this be a warning to my future self.

Comment: I would not rely on `cmd file >> file` consistently behaving in the way you want.

Comment: @JamesBrown the word you want is "illiterate" :-). To "alliterate" is to use words that all begin with the same letter.

Comment: (it's a reference to an old Mad magazine issue) Never realized there actually was a word _alliterate_. Apparently I should remove the word _computer_ from above.